# Pandas Equivalent of Excel Sumifs

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pandas-groupby, sumifs

I have a dataframe that is a table of units with their respective start dates, types, and capacities.

I have created a second dataframe that is a time series of the cumulative capacity of the units with two columns the the types, standard and exotic.

I'm having trouble using python to calculate the cumulative capacities for standard and exotic columns by date in the time series table.  What's the best way to accomplish this?

In excel I would create the time series table by using `sumifs` for each capacity type based upon unit start date and unit type.

```
=sumifs(capacity table['capacity' range], capacity table['start date' range],"<=" time series['date'],capacity table['type' range],"Standard")

=sumifs(capacity table['capacity' range], capacity table['start date' range],"<=" time series['date'],capacity table['type' range],"Exotic")
```

Capacity Table

| Unit | Start Date | Type | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/2021 | Standard | 10 |
| B | 01/03/2021 | Standard | 10 |
| C | 01/04/2021 | Standard | 10 |
| D | 01/05/2021 | Exotic | 15 |
| E | 01/07/2021 | Exotic | 15 |
| F | 01/09/2021 | Exotic | 15 |
| G | 01/10/2021 | Exotic | 15 |

Time Series

| Date | Standard Cap | Exotic Cap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 10 | 0 |
| 01/02/2021 | 10 | 0 |
| 01/03/2021 | 20 | 0 |
| 01/04/2021 | 30 | 0 |
| 01/05/2021 | 30 | 15 |
| 01/06/2021 | 30 | 15 |
| 01/07/2021 | 30 | 35 |
| 01/08/2021 | 30 | 30 |
| 01/09/2021 | 30 | 45 |
| 01/10/2021 | 30 | 60 |

Comment: In `Time Series`, should `Exotic Cap` on `01/07/2021` be 30 instead of 35?

Comment: You are correct.  It should be 30.  Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the capacity table:

[image]

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])

df['Standard Cap'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Capacity'] if row['Type'] == 'Standard' else 0,
    axis=1)
df['Exotic Cap'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Capacity'] if row['Type'] == 'Exotic' else 0,
    axis=1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(start=df.iloc[0,1], end=df.iloc[-1,1])})

df1 = df1.merge(df, how = 'left', left_on = 'Date', right_on = 'Start Date')

df1.drop(['Unit', 'Start Date', 'Type', 'Capacity'], inplace = True, axis=1)

df1.fillna(0, inplace = True)

df1['S_Cap_Cumulative'] = df1['Standard Cap'].cumsum()
df1['E_Cap_Cumulative'] = df1['Exotic Cap'].cumsum()
```

[image]

Can also drop the Standard and Exotic Cap columns with:

```
df1.drop(['Standard Cap', 'Exotic Cap'], inplace = True, axis=1)
```

Comment: No problem BlakeCrest1 (an upvote on the solution would be kind/helpful ;P )